Why are successive electron gain enthalpies after the first one always endothermic?
I wanted to know why is it that the first electron gain enthalpy can be positive or negative but second ones are always positive. I just do not understand why it should be true for elements like oxygen and sulphur. Their first enthalpy is negative, i.e, they release energy but on the addition of second one it is positive even though on the addition of second electron they can complete their subshell and should be very stable. Shouldn't this mean that they should release a lot of energy being stable?

Consider the standard fact of classical electrostatics that two negative charges like O-  and e- repulse each other.

Getting full shell is simply not enough. As long as it's a single atom, it's gonna spit the electron right out. If it were a big enough molecule, though...
